# If Yom Kippur hypothetically fell on Sunday, would you make havdalah?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, calendar, yom-kippur, havdalah

I was curious about this hypothetical situation.

If Yom Kippur would fall on Sunday, Motzei Shabbat, so immediately when Shabbat ends, Yom Kippur starts. Would there be some sort of separation, בין קודש לקודש, as we have when Yom Tov is Motzei Shabbat (in Shmoneh Esrei and Kiddush)?
Would we light candles?

The core of the question is, which has a higher *kedusha*?

On the one hand, Yom Kippur is called שבת שבתון, while Shabbat is only called שבת. On the other hand, we have 7 aliyot on Shabbat, and only 6 on Yom Kippur.

This question may actually become practical when we return בע"ה to the Sanhedrin setting each month's calendar.

Comment: In Shmot, 35:2, Shabbat is also called Shabbat shabbaton:  שֵׁשֶׁת יָמִים תֵּעָשֶׂה מְלָאכָה וּבַיּוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי יִהְיֶה לָכֶם קֹדֶשׁ שַׁבַּת שַׁבָּתוֹן לַיקֹוָק כָּל־הָעֹשֶׂה בוֹ מְלָאכָה יוּמָת

Comment: @Danno Someone (i don't remember who) says that this is actually referring to six days of Yom Tov (Pesach * 2, Sukkot * 2, Shavuot, Rosh Hashanah) and Yom Kippur.

Comment: +1, and I second Bruce James's welcome. But re "Would we light candles?": that seems highly improbable, as candle-lighting is a _m'lacha_, forbidden labor, on _Yom Kipur_. We don't, for example, light candles once _Shabas_ (any week) or _YK_ (any day of the week) has already begun, or toward the end of _Shabas_ for any Sunday _yom tov_.

Comment: @msh210 I agree that lighting candles would be unlikely, but i was curious anyhow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is discussed in the Talmud ([Shabbat 114](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=114b&format=pdf)) and the Rambam rules ([Shabbat 5:21](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3105.htm#21)) that no Havdallah is recited after Shabbat when Yom Kippur falls on Sunday.

Comment: You might be interested in Rambam [Eruvin 8:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3208.htm#10) or Shabbat 23:25.

Comment: Thank you. That Rambam is indeed interesting. It also seems to imply that if Yom Kippur is on Friday, we don't make havdalah between them, because they have the same level. The Gemara (and Rambam's quote) didn't deal with that case.

Answer (score -2):

The calendar is set such that Yom Kippur CANNOT occur on a Sunday.  Even if we went back to a system where the Sandhedrin declared the new moon, the problem remains of back to back shabbats.  This creates problems with regard to food preparation.  You would have to prepare food for both shabbat AND breaking fast Sunday night on Friday.  In other words, your hypothetical can't happen.  For the same reason, Yom Kippur cannot occur on a Friday.  You would still have back to back shabbats.

Comment: And would it be so terrible to have back-to-back shabbatot? People already end up preparing food for both Shabbat and Yom Tov when they are back-to-back. And i don't think that food is the actual problem here.

Comment: Actually, it is.  Your description is not accurate. Food preparation IS PERMITTED on Yom Tov, but not on shabbos or Yom Kippur. In ancient times, it was possible to prepare food to last through the 25 or so hours of shabbos, but if you add another 25 hours, it would not be possible to have food last 50 or so hours.  The rabbis in ancient times were careful not to make halakha too hard for the people to observe.

Comment: If you have Yom Tov on Motzei Shabbat, you don't have a lot of time to prepare some food. In any case, food isn't the question. This is modern and future times, where we do have technology to preserve food. Additionally, break-the-fast could be as simple as picking fresh fruit if it came to it.

Comment: This question is clearly marked as hypothetical. -1

Comment: It still needs to be a reasonable hypothetical.  If it can't happen, it can't happen.

Comment: If the calendar system gets changed, so it could happen. Food is not the issue.

Comment: @Scimonster Unless (just for the sake of argument) any change in the calendar has this not happening as an a priori requirement. If one could show that even when Sanhedrin declares the month, it can intervene if the declaration would create 2 Shabbatot in a row to change the claendar, then the hypothetical might be considered unreasonable. Of course, it is for others to show that in regards to Sanhedrin. I'm just watching the conversation.

Comment: "This creates problems with regard to food preparation. You would have to prepare food for both shabbat AND breaking fast Sunday night on Friday." When we have a _sanhedrin_ setting the calendar again (may it be soon!), we'll also have refrigeration and slow-cookers and so on. I don't see why we couldn't have _Yom Kipur_ on Sunday then. (IIRC -- and I may well not -- the other reason given for no _YK_ on Sunday is that someone who died at the start of _Shabas_ would rot for two days: but, again, we'll have refrigeration when the _sanhedrin_ starts setting the calendar again.)

Comment: I move for this non-answer to be deleted.

Comment: Even if you proved it could never happen (which I don't think you can because Beit Din can make mistakes), that doesn't mean it isn't a good thought experiment to help us learn about the nature of these holidays.

Comment: The same Rambam which says that Rosh HaShana [is not](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3807.htm) established in a way that Yom Kippur can fall out on Sunday, contemplates that it can happen when not using the calculations. These reasons (food, burial, or [kabbalistic](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/letters-rebbe-3/049.htm)) do not override actually following the moon. It is only when we aren't anyway following lunar observations that these concerns are predominant.

Comment: @DoubleAA, IMHO, it is fine to answer a hypothetical Halachic question with saying it is Halachically impossible (I think you could find examples of exactly that response in the Talmud). It is just that in this case it is wrong to say it is Halachically impossible. So I would say it is an answer, just in this case a wrong one.

Comment: @Yishai That's only true if that asker assumed it was possible. That's called rejecting a premise of the question. Since the OP stated this is hypothetical, I don't see how that argument form applies here.

Comment: @DoubleAA, he does suggest it is possible, in the last paragraph. But in any event, I think it is possible to answer that Halacha simply doesn't address the question because it is impossible.

Comment: I still encourage the OP to delete it...